# Regex/PHP Replace any repeating word group

Tags: php, regex

How can match

```
$string = "Foo Bar (Any Group - ANY GROUP Baz)";
```

Should return as "Foo Bar (Any Group - Baz)"

Is it possible without bruteforce as here [Replace repeating strings in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781942/replace-repeating-strings-in-a-string) ?

Edit:
* The group could consist of 1-4 words while each word could match `[A-Za-z0-9\/\(\)]{1,30}`
* The separator would always be `-`

Comment: Define "repeating word group" - does it have to be more than one word? How do you define a word? What separates words? How far may they be apart?

Comment: I think 2 notions are important for that:
- The minimal length of the repeated group.
- The possible separators between the groups.

Comment: The group could consist of 1-4 words while each word could match `[A-Za-z0-9 \/\(\)]{1,30}`

Comment: So if a space can be part of a word, how then are words separated from each other?

Comment: You are not really looking to replace a word, but an entire phrase which may be more difficult.

Comment: Ups, space not part of word of course. The separator would always be " - "

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leaving the space out of the list of allowed "word" characters, the following works for your example:

```
$result = preg_replace(
    '%
    (                 # Match and capture
     (?:              # the following:...
      [\w/()]{1,30}   # 1-30 "word" characters
      [^\w/()]+       # 1 or more non-word characters
     ){1,4}           # 1 to 4 times
    )                 # End of capturing group 1
    ([ -]*)           # Match any number of intervening characters (space/dash)
    \1                # Match the same as the first group
    %ix',             # Case-insensitive, verbose regex
    '\1\2', $subject);
```

Comment: Hi, I need to bump this old thread. Would it be possible to ignore possible blanks? So "(Any Group - ANYGROUP Baz)" would return "(Any Group - Baz)" ?

Comment: @Martin: I can think of an (ugly) way how this could work, but it would be a completely different approach than the one I've used here, so I think this should be put into a new question to avoid confusing people.